# Updating object for angular http post method after getting object

Tags: angular, http, post, get, rxjs

I want to update an object I first receive from a get request, then update, then put the object back in post. However, I am setting the data to an empty object ( {} )

```
var dataObject = {};
this.persistanceDataService.getData()
          .subscribe(data => {
            dataObject = data.contents;
            dataObject.ussInput = this.input_box;
            dataObject.ussData = this.data;
          })

this.persistanceDataService.setData(dataObject)
          .subscribe((res: any) => { });
```

Comment: Is this all the code you have? because it looks like you are calling the `setData()` service before the `getData()` has time to hit the database and return the information (since all service calls are asynchronous)

Answer (score 2):

First get the first observable, process it using `map`, then apply `switchMap` with the processed data to get the second observable. Finally subscribe:

```ts
 this.persistanceDataService.getData().pipe(
        map(data =>return{
        // process your data here
        }),

        switchMap(processedData =>{
        this.persistanceDataService.setData(processedData)
        })
        ).subscribe(x =>{})
```